# Ubuntu doesn't show up after complete installation

Tags: boot

My laptop - Dell Inspiron 5558, RAM: 8GB, Processor: Intel Core i5, graphics: 4GB

I successfully installed Ubuntu system on my laptop from bootable DVD yesterday.
Until that time no problems or errors were found. Then I removed my DVD from laptop and restarted my laptop, but after then now whenever I turn on my laptop it shows me this message:

```
No boot device found . Press any key to reboot the machine.
```

Comment: What did you actually install Ubuntu to? It seems that your motherboard can't detect a proper boot device, which means your Ubuntu installation broke- or, the device you installed Ubuntu to is no longer plugged in. I would try installing from a bootable usb, and make sure that you installed it to your hard drive.

Comment: Is ur laptop dual booted?where did u install? Ubuntu needs some unallocated space to install.

Comment: My problem is solved .. I got simple and easy solution for this problem ^_^

Comment: @SamiPatel This is a Q & A site, please post your solution as an answer here (and mark it accepted).

Comment: @melebius ... Done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this kind of error follow the steps given below :

1 )  set boot on secure mode (UFEI mode ) .. For this open boot settings  which can be open by Pressing f12 or f2 or f4 button repeatedly .

2)  now reinstall your linux system

3)  after completely install your system .. Restart your pc or laptop and open boot settings again

4) now go to BIOS Setup

5) go to general -> boot sequence -> add boot options

6) gives boot option name whatever you want ( if you give here your system name than it would be good .. Eg ubuntu , linux mint whatever ... )

7) file name : press browse -> find the ""shimx64.efl""  select it . press ok .. And restart machine .. Then your system will ready to run properly :)

Answer (score 0):

***First option***

try this if it does not work try below one.

Try entering your BIOS menu by entering **f10** or **f9** or **f12** or **delete** key OR any other key that you can try.

Once there, there will be an option for **boot order** and in that after selecting **OS boot** there will be options for choosing **windows OR ubuntu** as first option.

In my BIOS for rearranging I have to press **f6 and f5** yours may be different.

---

***second option***

Make a live Ubuntu USB or CD and boot to it.
Select "try Ubuntu without installing" Once there, open terminal and execute the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

After installing, open it by executing `boot-repair` and select **recommended repair** then follow on screen instructions.

After booting for first time  execute `sudo update-grub` to add all entries and you are good to go

Comment: Cannot add PPA : 'ppa:yannubur' . Please check that the PPA name or format is correct .

Comment: This error comes up

Comment: you are executing wrong command that is why it is giving error **please make sure each and every spelling is correct** you have written in error that it is ppa:'yannubr' means you are executing wrong command. *please check spellings before hitting ENTER**

Comment: And make sure you have working Internet.